# react navigation - navigate to a specific tab within a screen of two tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to react native navigation. I have two different tabs, one is called "Current" and one "History" and a DisplayScreen component which is responsible to show both tabs. The stack of this component in the navigation file is set like so:

```
function DisplayStack () { return (
    <Service.Navigator {...(css.DisplayStack || {})}>
        {screen(Service.Screen, 'DisplayScreen ', scr.DisplayScreen)}
    </Service.Navigator>)}
```

Then I have a tab stack with this DisplayStack:

```
function TabStack () { return (
    <Tab.Navigator {...TabStackParams}>
        {screen(Root.Screen, 'HomeStack', HomeStack)}
        {screen(Root.Screen, 'DisplayStack ', DisplayStack )}
    </Tab.Navigator>)}
```

Navigating to the DisplayStack is easy:

```
this.navigate('TabStack', { screen: 'DisplayStack ' })
```

But with the current functionality, navigating to it opens the component which is reponsible for displaying the two tabs. But how can I navigate to a specific tab inside this component? Should I change the way my navigation is constructed? Or send props to the DisplayScreen (which loads the two tabs) to tell it to open the desired screen out of the two?

Comment: If you name your screens correctly its easy to do that just call the screenname so DisplayScreen for example inside DisplayStack. this.props.navigation.navigate('DisplayScreen')

Comment: Thanks I mean that inside DisplayScreen I want to navigate to a specific tab/screen, which is 'history' or 'current'. I only have the DisplayScreen in my stack so I can only navigate to this screen that loads both tabs but then I don't have control of which tab to navigate to

Comment: have you found any solution for this??